# what is a way to set an on change event for appended inputs, but separately?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set an on change event (via jQuery) to an appended html template that contains inputs.
currently:

html

```
<div class="scroller" id='videoInfoColumn' style="height: 600px; overflow-x: hidden;text-align: left;">
  <button id="add-vid-btn">Add</button>
</div>
```

```js
let count = 0;
let htmlTemplate = `<div><input id="vidUpload" type="file" /></div>`

function f_create_video_loaders(count) {
  $(htmlTemplate).appendTo(videoInfoColumn);
  let videoInfoColumn = document.getElementById('videoInfoColumn');
    let vidUploadInput = document.getElementById('vidUpload');
    inputArrays.push(vidUploadInput);
    // console.log(inputArrays)

    
    vidUploadInput.setAttribute('id',`vidUpload${count}`)
    // on video upload
    
// here's where I need to run the on change event whenever a video got uploaded to that specific input.

    $('#vidUpload').on('change', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let files = e.target.files;
            
        videoInfoColumn.lastElementChild.remove()
        f_select_files(files);

        vidUploadInput.value = ''
        
        // // take off the change event
        $('#vidUpload').off('change');
    })
}

const addVidBtn = document.getElementById('add-vid-btn');
addVidBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  count++;
  f_create_video_loaders(count)
})
```

I'm having trouble trying to:

1. setting a unique id of the vidUpload input
2. running the on change event for just the specific vidUpload input.

I tried to set `` vidUploadInput.setAttribute('id',`vidUpload${count}`) ``,
with the count incrementing per each click of the `f_create_video_loaders()`.
And then tried to come up with some loop to fire the on change event for whenever an input gets uploaded with a video, but I just can't think of the logic properly.

At the moment, since all the inputs have the same id, it gives me the same file for each input appended. However, it works fine if I upload a file one by one.
-Append vidUpload
-Upload a video
-Append another vidUpload (via addVidBtn)
-Upload another video.
(this works, but not what I need)

My goal is

- Append x-number of inputs. Click 3 times, append input 3 times.
- Then, upload file in each input one by one before submitting to the back.

thank you

EDIT: Current Solution:

By your help (biberman and others) here is my current solution that seems to be working well.

```
function f_create_video_loaders(count) {

    // grab the main div to append video information
    const videoInfoColumn = document.getElementById('videoInfoColumn');
    
    // create a separate empty div to hold onto video info
    let myDiv = document.createElement('div');
    myDiv.id = "vidFormContainer_" + count;

    // create count_temp arg
    let jg_post_item_count_temp = "jg_postitem_" + count;
    // concat html template w/ set args to newly created div
    myDiv.innerHTML += f_set_html_element_template(count, {name: "no file"}, jg_post_item_count_temp);
    // append div into the main videoInfoColumn div of the html
    videoInfoColumn.append(myDiv);

    // create the input
    const vidUploadInput = document.createElement('input');
    vidUploadInput.id = 'vidUpload_' + count;
    vidUploadInput.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    vidUploadInput.setAttribute('accept', 'video/*');
    // console.log(vidUploadInput);

    // append the input to proper location in the html template
    let idArr = vidUploadInput.id.split('_');
    let idNum = idArr[1];
    let videoSelectorContainer = document.getElementById('append_video_' + idNum);
    videoSelectorContainer.append(vidUploadInput)

    $('#xitm_publish_from_date_' + count).datepicker({
                format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
                language: "ja",
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true,
                startView: 1
            });

        $('#xitm_publish_to_date_' + count).datepicker({
            format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
            language: "ja",
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            startView: 1
        });

    // handle change
    function changeHandler(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let files = e.target.files;

        //hide video input
        vidUploadInput.style.display = 'none';

        // create video player
        let source = document.createElement('video');
        source.id = ''
        source.style.width = '100%';
        source.controls = true;
        source.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0])
        //append to main video container
        videoSelectorContainer.append(source);
        
        // grab id
        let idArr = vidUploadInput.id.split('_');
        let idNum = idArr[1];
        let fileTitle = document.getElementById('xitm_attachment_file_name_' + idNum);
        // update file title
        fileTitle.value = files[0].name;

        let w_count_id = parseInt(f_jg_array_get_max(displaying_video_data_array, "w_count_id")) + 1;
        let w_counter = w_count_id;
        displaying_video_data_array.push({
            name: files[0].name,
            class: "jg_postitem_" + count,
            upload_name: files[0].name,
            w_count_id: w_count_id,
            video_id: ""
        })

        w_video_formData.append('file[]'       , files[0]);
        w_video_formData.append('file_name[]'  , files[0].name);

        console.log(w_video_formData);
        // take off the change event
        vidUploadInput.removeEventListener('change', changeHandler)
    }
    
    // inputArrays.unshift(vidUploadInput);
    vidUploadInput.addEventListener('change', changeHandler);
    
}
```

Comment: Why you need "separate" events? Change `$('#vidUpload').off('change');` to `$(this).off('change')`. Also why mixing VanillaJS with jQuery?

Comment: `since all the inputs have the same id` - work on classes, not on ID's

Comment: You don't use the var `htmlTemplate`. How do you append that input?

Comment: I don't fully understand your goal. You want to upload the files from all inputs when one input is changed. But after each change you reset the value of the changed input to an empty string and delete the last input even when it isn't the changed input. So there will never be multiple files to upload.

Comment: Furthermore: What do you mean with "*before submitting to the back*"?

Comment: And why do you want to remove the eventListener?

Comment: sorry for the confusion @biberman I want to append inputs depending on number of clicks on the add btn. click twice, get two inputs. Then, I want the user to be able to upload vid files inside the two inputs (or how many inputs they want to append). It's fine if it is just: click add input, then upload file. click add input, then upload file (that's why I put empty string and delete the last input (f_select_file will switch the template to the one needed to send to the db). need to keep this code since it is part of the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some issues:

- you don't use the var `htmlTemplate`
- `${blankHtmlElement}` isn't defined - here you should use the above var
- you try to select the element `#vidUpload` before you append it
- `inputArrays` isn't defined
- you append the `change` listener to an element with the id `vidUpload` that doesn't exist because you overwrite the id by adding the index `count` to it - instead you should append the listener to the actually created input `$(vidUploadInput)`

If you define `inputArrays`, use `htmlTemplate` for the appending and move the appending before the selection of `#vidUpload` it works as expected.

**Working example:**

```js
let count = 0;
let inputArrays = [];
let htmlTemplate = `<div><input id="vidUpload" type="file" /></div>`;

function f_create_video_loaders(count) {
  let videoInfoColumn = document.getElementById('videoInfoColumn');
  $(htmlTemplate).appendTo(videoInfoColumn);
  let vidUploadInput = document.getElementById('vidUpload');
  inputArrays.push(vidUploadInput);
  // console.log(inputArrays);

  vidUploadInput.setAttribute('id', `vidUpload${count}`);
  // on video upload

  // here's where I need to run the on change event whenever a video got uploaded to that specific input.

  $(vidUploadInput).on('change', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let files = e.target.files;

    videoInfoColumn.lastElementChild.remove();
    
    console.log(files);
    //f_select_files(files);

    vidUploadInput.value = '';

    // take off the change event
    $(vidUploadInput).off('change');
  })
}

const addVidBtn = document.getElementById('add-vid-btn');
addVidBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  count++;
  f_create_video_loaders(count);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="scroller" id='videoInfoColumn' style="height: 600px; overflow-x: hidden;text-align: left;">
  <button id="add-vid-btn">Add</button>
</div>
```

---

**By the way:** You don't need jQuery for that and do it with plain JavaScript:

```js
let count = 0;
let inputArrays = [];

function f_create_video_loaders(count) {
  let videoInfoColumn = document.getElementById('videoInfoColumn');
  let container = document.createElement('div');
  let vidUploadInput = document.createElement('input');
  
  function changeHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let files = e.target.files;

    videoInfoColumn.lastElementChild.remove();
    
    console.log(files);
    //f_select_files(files);

    vidUploadInput.value = '';

    // take off the change event
    vidUploadInput.removeEventListener('change', changeHandler)
  }
  
  vidUploadInput.type = 'file';
  vidUploadInput.id = 'vidUpload' + count;
  vidUploadInput.addEventListener('change', changeHandler);
  
  inputArrays.push(vidUploadInput);
  container.append(vidUploadInput);
  videoInfoColumn.append(container);
}

const addVidBtn = document.getElementById('add-vid-btn');
addVidBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  count++;
  f_create_video_loaders(count);
})
```

```html
<div class="scroller" id='videoInfoColumn' style="height: 600px; overflow-x: hidden;text-align: left;">
  <button id="add-vid-btn">Add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @biberman. This does work on my end as well (typo mistakes when I typed on here), but the problem is that the `input.files` will continue to change to whichever input got the latest file. it works if I append 1 input and upload a video file, one at a time. The goal is to append n-inputs, and then upload video files in each inputs, then send it via the `f_select_files()`. still trying!

Comment: thank you for the support. I think this helped me get going a bit better. Now, I am trying to append the video source inside the changeHandler from the file and append it to the div per found by id + count. Will post solution when (or if) done.

Answer (score 0):

Please use your element as array then only it will post the multiple files

`vidUploadInput.setAttribute('name', 'vidUpload[]')`

`vidUploadInput.setAttribute('class', 'vidUpload')`

`<input id="vidUpload" class="vidUpload" name="vidUpload[]" type="file" />`

```
$(document).on("change",".vidUpload",function(e) {
Your code here });
```

Comment: thanks for the thought, but the goal isn't to post multiple files. I want to be able to append input on each click, and then upload files in each individual input (separate, different video files).

Comment: @funtkungus I have updated my answer, so please use a class attribute with the default file element and add new attribute of class using js same as id, name, and use the input change event as mentioned in my answer. I hope it will help you now.